# Dynamic python module import and numba

Tags: python, numba, python-importlib

I have a module and a module loader. The module uses numba.

When I call the module's function after it's dynamically loaded using `importlib`, I've got several errors.
When I do a `static` import and call the function, everything works fine.

When I don't use numba, both, static and dynamic import are working fine.

Here is a simple example to reproduce the problem:

The module `mymod.py`:

```py
from numba import jit

@jit(nopython=True)
def process():
    a = 5
    res = a + 5
    return res
```

The module loader that works: `runb.py` (static import)

```py
import mymod

def main():
    res = mymod.process()
    print(res)

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

The module loader that doesn't work: `run.py` (dynamic import)

```py
from pathlib import Path
import importlib.util

def main():
    module_path = "./mymod.py"
    spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(Path(module_path).name, module_path) 
    module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
    spec.loader.exec_module(module)

    res = module.process()

    print(res)

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Software context:

- Ubuntu   **19.04**
- Python   **3.7.5**
- pip      **18.1**
- Numba    **0.51.2**
- llvmlite **0.34.0**

Folder view:

- dumb/venv
- dumb/mymod.py
- dumb/run.py
- dumb/runb.py

I'm struggling with this issue and not finding anything on the internet.

Below the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mypath/dumb/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/core/environment.py", line 21, in from_fndesc
    return cls._memo[fndesc.env_name]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/weakref.py", line 137, in __getitem__
    o = self.data[key]()
KeyError: '_ZN08NumbaEnv5mymod2py11process$241E'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mypath/dumb/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/core/funcdesc.py", line 93, in lookup_module
    return sys.modules[self.modname]
KeyError: 'mymod.py'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 16, in <module>
    main()
  File "run.py", line 10, in main
    res = module.process()
  File "mypath/dumb/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/core/dispatcher.py", line 434, in _compile_for_args
    raise e
  File "mypath/dumb/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/core/dispatcher.py", line 367, in _compile_for_args
    return self.compile(tuple(argtypes))
  File "mypath/dumb/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/core/compiler_lock.py", line 32, in _acquire_compile_lock
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "mypath/dumb/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/core/dispatcher.py", line 819, in compile
    cres = self._compiler.compile(args, return_type)
  File "mypath/dumb/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/core/dispatcher.py", line 78, in compile
    status, retval = self._compile_cached(args, return_type)
  File "mypath/dumb/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/core/dispatcher.py", line 92, in _compile_cached
    retval = self._compile_core(args, return_type)
  File "mypath/dumb/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/core/dispatcher.py", line 110, in _compile_core
    pipeline_class=self.pipeline_class)
  File "mypath/dumb/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/core/compiler.py", line 627, in compile_extra
    return pipeline.compile_extra(func)
  File "mypath/dumb/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/core/compiler.py", line 363, in compile_extra
    return self._compile_bytecode()
  File "mypath/dumb/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/core/compiler.py", line 425, in _compile_bytecode
    return self._compile_core()
  File "mypath/dumb/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/core/compiler.py", line 405, in _compile_core
    raise e
  File "mypath/dumb/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/core/compiler.py", line 396, in _compile_core
    pm.run(self.state)
  File "mypath/dumb/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/core/compiler_machinery.py", line 341, in run
    raise patched_exception
  File "mypath/dumb/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/core/compiler_machinery.py", line 332, in run
    self._runPass(idx, pass_inst, state)
  File "mypath/dumb/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/core/compiler_lock.py", line 32, in _acquire_compile_lock
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "mypath/dumb/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/core/compiler_machinery.py", line 291, in _runPass
    mutated |= check(pss.run_pass, internal_state)
  File "mypath/dumb/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/core/compiler_machinery.py", line 264, in check
    mangled = func(compiler_state)
  File "mypath/dumb/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/core/typed_passes.py", line 442, in run_pass
    NativeLowering().run_pass(state)
  File "mypath/dumb/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/core/typed_passes.py", line 369, in run_pass
    metadata=metadata)
  File "mypath/dumb/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/core/lowering.py", line 37, in __init__
    self.env = Environment.from_fndesc(self.fndesc)
  File "mypath/dumb/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/core/environment.py", line 23, in from_fndesc
    inst = cls(fndesc.lookup_globals())
  File "mypath/dumb/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/core/funcdesc.py", line 81, in lookup_globals
    return self.global_dict or self.lookup_module().__dict__
  File "mypath/dumb/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/core/funcdesc.py", line 96, in lookup_module
    f"can't compile {self.qualname}: "
ModuleNotFoundError: can't compile process: import of module mymod.py failed
```

Comment: I think, the name for `spec_from_file_location(name, path)` should be `mymod`, not `mymod.py`.

Comment: I've replaced the line by: 

```spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location("mymod", module_path)```

Still the same problem :/

Comment: So you still get `KeyError: 'mymod.py'`?

Comment: Have you figured it out?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a way to prevent the first exception from happening. But the second

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mypath/dumb/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/core/funcdesc.py", line 93, in lookup_module
    return sys.modules[self.modname]
KeyError: 'mymod.py'
```

is easy to fix.

Add the module to the mentioned `sys.modules` dictionary to make it accessible by its filename during the `exec_module(module)` call.

```py
from pathlib import Path
import importlib.util
import sys

def main():
    module_path = "./mymod.py"
    spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(Path(module_path).name, module_path) 
    module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
    sys.modules[spec.name] = module
    spec.loader.exec_module(module)

    res = module.process()

    print(res)

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Output

```
10
```